# How to remove a text from a variable? (php)

Tags: php, regex

I have a variable `$link_item`, it's used with `echo` and gives the strings like

```
<span class="name">Google</span>http://google.com
```

**How to remove "**`<span class="name">Google</span>`**" from string?**

It should give just "http://google.com".

Heard it can be done with `regex()`, please help.

Comment: What is the difference each time? What can differ, and what stays the same?

Comment: I agree with @Ikke. Please give some more examples of the contents of `$link_item`. The current example does not provide enough information for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solved:

```
$contents = '<span class="name">Google</span>http://google.com';
$new_text = preg_replace('/<span[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/span[^>]*>/', '', $contents);
echo $new_text;

// outputs -> http://google.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Without regex:

```
echo substr($link_item, stripos($link_item, 'http:'))
```

But this only works if the first part (i.e. `<span class="name">Google</span>`) never contains `http:`. If you can assure this: here you go :)

Reference: [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php), [`stripos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

**Update:**

As @Gordon points out in his comment, my code is doing the same as [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) already does. I just put it here in case one does not read the comments:

```
echo strstr($link_item, 'http://');
```

Comment: @Gordon, don't waste your time :)

Comment: @Glister I know that @Felix appreciates constructive criticism, so it's not wasted on him.

Comment: @Gordon: I was not aware of this function. You are right. And yes it is not wasted, I am always happy to learn :)

Comment: @Gordon: I added your comment to my answer. If you want to provide your own answer with this solution, I will delete it again.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = '<span class="name">Google</span>http://google.com';
$pieces = explode("</span>",$string);
//In case there is more than one span before the URL
echo $pieces[count($pieces) -1];
```

Comment: What about multiple, nested or none `<span>` s ?. Of course we can only assume here as the OP doesn't give  enough information. So "assuming" that there will never be a `<span>` after the URL, maybe this is more robust: `echo $pieces[count($pieces) -1 ]` (just get the last element of the array).

Comment: $string doesn't everytime have "<span>". Thanks for try.

Comment: @Felix: why assuming more than necessary? Just stick to the question, if it turns out to be incomplete the OP will extend it. There is no point in considering 100 possibilities when the case could be just one.

Comment: Indeed, I was working on the assumption that every $string would contain one span and one URL (in that order). If this is not the case my code won't work..

Comment: @kemp: Sometimes it doesn't hurt to think a little further ;) (only if it involves small changes to the original solution, of course there is no point in considering everything). In fact, I like this solution very much. I just added a thought.

Comment: @calumbrodie: If you consider the small change in my comment, it even if no `<span>` is present.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a regex. Use a [HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to extract only the text you want from it.

Comment: Would you really load an external module just for this trivial substitution?

Comment: I think people are just afraid of another meltdown: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags And of course it depends on whether the HTML of `$link_item` ever changes, which I'm guessing it may one day.

Answer (score 0):

**Made myself**

```
$link_item_url = preg_replace('@<span[^>]*?>.*?</span>@si', '', $link_item);
```

This will remove any `<span + something + </span>` from variable `$link_item`.

Thanks for all.

Comment: why minus? I think this is the best solution

Comment: -1 for wasting people's time by asking a question the OP apparently could solve himself without help. I'd give another -1 for the misuse of Regex and another -1 for not providing the requested information to the question. But I can only downvote once.

Comment: It would still be nice if you could provide us more information about the structure of `$link_item`.

Comment: @Gordon: how is it inefficient?

Comment: @Gordon, I had no idea hot to fix when this post was published.

Comment: You said in my answer that "$string doesn't everytime have "<span>". Thanks for try"

In that case your code would not work!

Comment: @calumbrodie, don't know how, but my solution works like expected

Comment: @kemp for simple string replacements, regex are almost always the slower alternative. For the example given in the question, a simple strstr would suffice.

Comment: @Glister Sorry, but that's not good enough, I've downvoted your question.